# How to get total wins for two players playing together?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table named `playergame`.

| id | gameid | player | win |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | jon | true |
| 2 | 1 | dan | true |
| 3 | 1 | lee | false |
| 4 | 2 | jon | false |
| 5 | 2 | jon | true |
| 6 | 3 | lee | true |

I want to get all games where jon and dan have won playing together. I think I may be able to do this with something like:

```
SELECT count(*) as wins
FROM playergame
WHERE player = 'dan' AND player = 'jon' AND win = true
GROUP BY gameid
```

However I need to factor in that I'm wanting to merge and query two rows into 1. How can I do this?

Comment: In gameid=2 Jon has 2 rows with win = true and false. How is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you only want gameid , here is the simplest way :

```
select gameid 
from playergame
where player in ('jon' , 'don')
and win = true
group by gameid
having count(distinct player) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

PIVOT will give you a table format that works for your purpose. With PIVOT you can generate a table that has one line per gameid and then one column per player and the value true and false for each player for each game id.

To learn more about how to use PIVOT, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server).

Then you can use the query

```
SELECT count(*) as wins
FROM playergame_pivot
WHERE Column_Dan = true AND Column_Jon = true
```